# How to control the order of meshing？

Tags: mesh

I want the first pic，but i got the second. What can I do?
[image]

[image]

Below if the code to produce the second pic:

```
data = {{14.808253637272422`, 
    5.992415735398138`, -10}, {14.937895181494618`, 
    5.835230243884557`, -10}, {15.104476099263962`, 
    6.190504320078969`, -10}, {15.549905577158725`, 
    6.242337037739479`, -10}, {16.214292480395272`, 
    5.946484831244263`, -10}, {17.172819193670374`, 
    6.044620763590807`, -10}, {14.808281657120743`, 
    5.992346489742819`, -5}, {14.937944420202394`, 
    5.83506166050832`, -5}, {15.104458590180693`, 
    6.1905995697624006`, -5}, {15.549909194291196`, 
    6.242289007293565`, -5}, {16.21428558314019`, 
    5.946304785847829`, -5}, {17.172828128632702`, 
    6.044675503473975`, -5}, {14.808370059168467`, 5.992128021118139`,
     0}, {14.93796801813446`, 5.834980865961923`, 
    0}, {15.104521660293425`, 6.190256467374961`, 
    0}, {15.549917959537805`, 6.242172617112528`, 
    0}, {16.214298214579777`, 5.946634515939104`, 
    0}, {17.172827172286173`, 6.044669644434473`, 
    0}, {14.808196500526428`, 5.992556937854838`, 
    5}, {14.937952476296239`, 5.835034078072448`, 
    5}, {15.104459789437353`, 6.190593045787643`, 
    5}, {15.549890996009355`, 6.242530654951938`, 
    5}, {16.21428524490538`, 5.946295956593386`, 
    5}, {17.17285709312181`, 6.044852953886377`, 
    5}, {14.808354331354467`, 5.992166889379481`, 
    10}, {14.937875586457652`, 5.835297333327767`, 
    10}, {15.1044365297471`, 6.190719578861889`, 
    10}, {15.549897447086584`, 6.242444993694446`, 
    10}, {16.214291019501033`, 5.946446696177589`, 
    10}, {17.172815114360944`, 6.044595771776242`, 10}};

pica = Graphics3D[Sphere[data, 0.1]]

picb = ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]

Show[pica, picb]
```

Comment: @Kuba Deleted my comments since there's no need to save them for posterity.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the data is that those are sets of almost vertical lines, so it is not a function on `{x,y}` domain. `ListPlot3D` is trying to get such surface but it is impossible.

We can use the trick to plot not `{x,y,z}` but `{z, x, y}` which is a function on `{z, x}`.

```
data2 = data[[ ;; , {3, 1, 2}]];

pica = Graphics3D[Sphere[data2, 0.1]];

picb = ListPlot3D[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #3 &}, 
                         Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All];

Show[pica, picb, ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"z", "x", "y"}, 
                 BoxRatios -> {5, 2, 1}, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 18}]
```

[image]